# Pink eye/Conjunctivitis or URI?

Tags: cats, health, veterinarian, eye-disease, upper-respiratory-disease

TL;DR at bottom

I've gotten a kitten at the start of this month (September). From the first day, she has had eye discharge in one eye, and has to sneeze every now and then. I was concerned, and brought her to the vet. The vet told me it's a conjunctivitis, and gave me some eye drops I'm supposed to give her up to 4 times a day. As most can imagine, the kitten isn't a fan of me holding her still and dropping something in her eye, so I've done it only 1-2 a day. While her eye did get better, it seems to have "stopped" healing for almost 1 week now. Her third eye lid is visible a bit, and it seems to be more red compared to the other "good" eye. The eye drops i received are on natural basis. Active ingredients: plant extract "eyebright" and Povidon.
The vet said that eye discharge is always accompanied by sneezing.

I'm starting to suspect it might be a URI rather than only a conjunctivitis.
Internet research shows that a normal conjunctivitis usually heals in 5-7 days, even without treatment. Since more than a week passed already, I'm a bit concerned.

The eye discharge is clear/transparent, although at the inner corner of the eye where it "gathers", its yellow. Her eye is not glued together or anything. The snot when she sneezes is also mostly clear/transparent. What do you guys think?

I have an appointment with the vet next week because she needs to get her second vaccine, so I can ask then. Although I'm curious if the vet will even do the vaccine if she sees that her eye is still not completely fine.

**TL;DR
Bought cat at start of September. She is sneezing and has dischrage on one eye. Vet said it's conjunctivitis and gave me eyedrops on natural basis. Eye discharge got better, but hasn't healed completely yet. There was no visible improvement in the past week and the kitten is still sneezing. Eye discharge and snot both bright/transparent. New vet appointment next week for second vaccination. Should i do something before then or wait?**

Thanks.

Comment: Has your vet figured it out, yet? If not: what breed is it? Some breeds actually suffer from chronic eye discharge, sometimes accompanied by sneezing. All our 4 cats do, due to their genetics. We usually grab half of a paper tissue to clean the area and soak up any liquid around the eyes in a calm and careful manner. If there's something crusty, you can use a wet cloth (e.g. piece of a cotton t-shirt) to remove that.